# How I can open a page in a new window and send data?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've been trying this for 2 days.
In ASP.NET and VB.NET I've page1.aspx and page2.aspx
I would like when I press button1 in page1.aspx to trigger button1.click event and open a page2.aspx in a new window and send to it data.
All this can easly be done if no new window, by Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect.
But unfortunatly they don't have an option to open a new window.

Thanks,

Ahmed.

-- Updae --
I've used this solution but can't send the parameters and it opens me page 0 !!

```
    <asp:Button ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick ="return pageOpen(TextBox1.SelectedValue, TextBox2.SelectedValue);"/>
```

and the javascript is:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function pageOpen()
    {
        window.open("page2.aspx?param1=" & arguments[0] & "&param2=" & arguments[1])
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by Page 0? your javascript pageOpen has no parameters defined....

Comment: I can't send parameters to function pageOpen(), so it opens for me a page like this: http://mysite/0 , but if I hard coded the parameters in window.open then it opens the page2.aspx in a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function openWindow() {
window.open('Page2.aspx?Arg1=' + document.getElementById('<%= txt1.ClientID %>').value + '&Arg2=' + document.getElementById('<%= txt2.ClientID %>').value, 'Title');
}


<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn" Text="Add" OnClientClick="openWindow()" runat="server" />
```

This should work...

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `window.open` in Javascript with the data in the querystring.

Comment: I tried this solution but its not sending the parameters and opening a page 0 !!

Comment: @user546995: the parameters have to be part of the query string.